# What will happen if you attach the negative pole of welder to the rotor of the motor or the body , will that cause problem?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I have built a machine that rotates a cylinder to weld it, I have to attache a negative pole to the cylinder which is connected directly to the rotor of motor, the motor is controled by an Abb vfd ACS150 with 0.55kw 380v 3.6A (motor characteristics 0.5kw, star connection 380v and 1000 rpm, I am welding with 300A and 30V) will that cause any issue to motor and vfd or not?

Comment: Abb vfd ACS150 with 0.55kw 380v 3.6A controls motor of 0.5kw, star connection 380v and 1000 rpm , the negative pole of welder will touche the cylinder hence the rotor of motor , I am welding with 300A and 30V

Comment: I would not weld on an active VFD.  But drives don't have to connect to attached cylinders via a conductive coupler, flexible rubber couplings exist.

Answer (score 0):

- Isolate the thing being welded from the motor, or from anything that has bearings that may eventually lead to ground.  You can only run that much current through a good bearing once -- after that it's a bad bearing.
- If your item being welded only goes through one or two turns, arrange for your return path to come out at the center of rotation, and just clamp to it with your welder's return lead.  Let it wind up as you're welding, then make sure to unwind it before you weld up the next thing.
- If you absolutely must let it rotate more than a limited number of turns, then I'm out of suggestions -- other than thinking that this has probably been done routinely since the 1940's, so solutions must exist.